# changing img src inside a a href using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following html:

```
<li>
   <a href=\"p://emotion/appreciate\" onclick=\"flip()\">
        <img src=\"smile.png\" />
   </a>
</li>
```

Basically, I want the flip function to replace the src of the img enclosed in it to smile-inactive when pressed, and change it back again to smile.png if it's now already in smile-inactive.png. How can I do this without having to do document.getElementById if I don't want to give the img an id?

Comment: This is a task that a framework like jQuery can really help with. Will save you a lot of time and head ache with browser compatibility.

Comment: Why not give the image an ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your flip function, I would make sure that `this` points to the anchor you just clicked, then grab the `img` as the first childNode:

```
<a href=\"p://emotion/appreciate\" onclick=\"flip.call(this)\">

function flip(){
    var img = this.children[0];
    if (/smile\.png/.test(img.src))
        img.src = "smile-inactive.png";
    else
        img.src = "smile.png"
}
```

---

**EDIT**

As `@am not i am` points out, you can achieve a slight gain in browser support by switching

```
var img = this.children[0];
```

to

```
var img = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```

Comment: Ah, you fixed both corrections I was going to suggest. +1 but to be just a wee bit more correct, I'd escape the `.` in the regex. Should't make an actual difference though.

Comment: @amnotiam - indeed - escaped.  Yeah, I forgot childNodes gives you text nodes too, while children only gives you the "good stuff" :)  -- I'm not the dom ninja you are!

Comment: I'm not a DOM ninja... I just play one on StackOverflow. That said, you could pick up a little more browser support with `getElementsByTagName` instead of `children`, but really you're only gaining FF3, so who cares.

Comment: ...love that you use `.call()` BTW.

Comment: @amnotiam - yeah, we've had that conversation - passing `this` as a param is soooooo cheesy.  BTW - congrats on the rep - looks like we'll be welcoming you into the 10K club here pretty soon

Answer (score 0):

Take both images, merge them to one, and just use offset to determine which one is shown.
You can do it by simply by CSS.

Comment: CSS won't help with click events though. If we were talking about a `:hover`, I'd totally agree.

Comment: I know what you mean, and I agree as well, Just wanted to prevent to load of two different images.

Comment: Yeah, it's still a good idea. Would just need a little JS to swap a class.